# Do it trigger when you close an iOS web APP?

Tags: php, ios

So while beeing bored, continuing on my PHP project FastTalk, I got stuck in the offline and online feature. Basically what I have done so far is that whenever the client uses the web app(saved to the desktop), it will update their online row in the MySQL database. But the thing is, I'm stuck in the part when the client exits the web app using the homescreen button or the lock button. I basically need to know if there's any way to run a PHP function when the client leaves the web app. Even if it's still running in the background. Here's a few screenshots I tried to make examples of:
[image]

---

**Edit:**
I have now created a working JavaScript 1minute check that will update the MySQL row to true every 1 minute, because JavaScript will always run if the client are on the website. But how can I set the row to false when the client aren't running the interval anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In the AppDelegate.m file

There are methods called DidEnterBackground and WillTerminate
The app will call DidEnterBackground when you minimize the app and WillTerminate when you kill it.

Hope it solves

Answer (score 0):

The only bulletproof way is to have your app send a heartbeat request to the server periodically to indicate that it's still online. Keep the timestamp of the last heartbeat in your DB, and consider users offline when they haven't sent a heartbeat since a given threshold.

AppDelegate methods are useless here, because you don't have enough time to finish an HTTP request when the app is about to terminate. Also your user can lose her internet connection, in which case it's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: In other words have a loop then when it don't run anymore, set the user as offline?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a simple loop. You should use a timer which triggers your heartbeat request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded with it using JavaScript to check whenever the client exits..
Here's how the code would be if anyone else would ever have the same problem:

```
window.onbeforeunload = logout;
function logout() {
    $.get("index.php?offline");
}
```